# Удаление всех файлов из репозитория

Tags: git

Попытка удалить все файлы с репозитория заканчивается ошибкой:

```
$ git rm -r *
```

> > error: the following files have changes staged in the index:

Как понимать эту ошибку? Что нужно сделать для удаления?

Comment: Видимо у Вас есть незакоммиченные файлы. Покажите вывод git status.

Comment: Changes to be committed:
Зеленным цветом 12 файлов.

Comment: вот вот. закомитье их (git commit).

Comment: При попытке комита я получаю -  Please tell me who you are: email,name

Comment: вам необходимо войти в систему, ибо на данный момент нет данных о вашей учетной записи. например, вот так: `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"`

Comment: подозреваю, что вообще не было ни одного коммита. Тогда может просто удалить файлы и каталог .git.

Comment: Как войти в систему ? git config и так далее после чего что дальше ?

Comment: При git config list - error: key does not contain a section:list

Comment: При git config -- user.name я получаю свой юзер
При git config -- user.email я получаю свой имейл.

Comment: Не то чтобы "войти в систему", а скорее установить базовые настройки гита. Выполните инструкции на этой странице: https://githowto.com/ru/setup?_=1452811688537

Comment: А вообще рекомендую пройти хотя бы первых пару глав учебника, прежде чем делать что-то вроде удаления всех файлов.

Comment: Дело было в создании конфигураций. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**предуведомление**: вопрос об осмысленности самого действия по удалению всех файлов из репозитория я не рассматриваю: вдруг, действительно, *так надо*.

---

полный текст сообщения звучит так:

> error: the following file has changes staged in the index:
>   список файлов
>   (use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)

если ваша задача — действительно удалить файлы, то воспользуйтесь второй подсказкой, добавив опцию `-f`

```
$ git rm -rf *
```

после этого, понятно, надо будет закрепить эти изменения в репозитории с помощью команды `commit`:

```
$ git commit
```

---

возникает же подобная ошибка из-за того, что вы с помощью команды `add` [добавили в индекс](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch07.html#_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_git) какие-то изменения (новый файл или изменения уже отслеживаемого), но не закрепили их *commit-ом*.